# Display multiline text with tab support in iOS

Tags: ios, text, textview

I need to show a body of text for the 'Terms and Conditions' section of my clients iPad app. This needs to be formatted in a particular way with tab support at etc. This body of text also needs to be scrollable as well.

I would like the end resulting text to be formatted as the bellow example screenshot.

[image]

Using UITextView is no good as it does not respect the tabs and other attributes on the body of text.

Any advice is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You could use `UIWebView`.

Comment: Hi Adil Soomro, thanks for the answer. I actually took your advice and it works pretty well. I posed an answer below on what I did for the benefit of someone else who might be looking at the question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a library where you can have formatted text in a textview. Just check it out and see if it is useful for you

https://github.com/FuerteInternational/FTCoreText

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this uses a 'markup syntax' which means I have to go through text and re-format it according to the 'markup syntax'. Which I don't think what I need, because the body of text might change in the future and I don't want to do 'markup syntax' each time that happens.

And I found a work around using 'UIWebView'. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of someone else reading this questions I decided to post what I ended up doing.

I ended up using a `UIWebView` for this.

What I did was

- Create a html page out of the formatted text (I used MS Word to export the text into a html file, but you can use pretty much anything you want as long as the outputted html is formatted the way you want)
- add html to xCode project
- load html on to a `UIWebView`like such

  ```
  NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TermsConditionsAgreement" ofType:@"html"];
  NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
  [_webview setOpaque:NO];
  [_webview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
  ```

By using `setOpaque:NO` and setting WebView's background color to 'Clear Color' the web view will display text on a transparent background.